# WCF rest webservice in Azure Web Role - 404 error

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, azure

I have searched through stack exchange and while there are many similar questions to this I have not been able to sole this problem.
I need to run a WCF web service on an Azure webrole (as I am running regular web pages also) and not a Azure Web Service role.
I have setup a WCF service and defined the endpoints in the web.config but I am not able to connect to the endpoint through my browser or through a client.
Below is the code - would really appreciate it if someone can advise as to what might be going wrong.

Given the code below I would assume that the following would work in the browser

```
http://127.0.0.1:81/testAPI.svc/store/
```

but I get a 404 on that
If i just specify

```
http://127.0.0.1:81/testAPI.svc
```

I get the page telling me that I have a web service.

**ItestAPI.cs**

```
namespace MvcWebRole1
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ItestAPI
    {


        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "store",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        List<Financials> GetStoreActuals();
    }
}
```

**testAPI.svc**

```
namespace MvcWebRole1
{

    public class testAPI : ItestAPI
    {
            public List<Financials> GetStoreActuals()
            {
                return GetActuals();

            }

            private List<Financials> GetActuals()
            {

                List<Financials> Actuals = new List<Financials>
                {
                    new Financials
                    {
                    Store = "Store1", Profit = "10000000", Sales = "2000000"
                    },
                    new Financials
                    {
                    Store = "Store2", Profit = "20000000", Sales = "30000"
                    },
                    new Financials
                    {
                    Store = "Store3", Profit = "30000000", Sales = "4000000"
                    },
                    new Financials
                    {
                    Store = "Store4", Profit = "4000000", Sales = "500000"
                    },

                };
                return Actuals;
            }

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Financials
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Store { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Sales { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Profit { get; set; }


    }
}
```

and finally the service model in **web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="servicebehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restbehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name ="MvcWebRole1.testAPI" behaviorConfiguration ="servicebehavior" >
        <endpoint name ="RESTEndPoint"
        contract ="MvcWebRole1.ItestAPI"
        binding ="webHttpBinding"
        address =""
        behaviorConfiguration ="restbehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Thanks very much for ANY help here!

Comment: Also when I try and access this through a client application I get the following exception Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MvcWebRole1.ItestAPI' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the following:
If I setup a WCFServiceWebRole using the above classes and config then it all worked perfectly. It was only an issue when trying to run the above in an MCVWebRole.

After playing around with MVCWebRole web.config I finally got it to work. As you can probably tell I am new to .NET but removing the following from my MVWWebRole solved the problem. I am sure there will be consequences to this but at least I have isolated the issue.

Just thought I would share in case it helps anyone else out.

This is what I removed

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

If someone can tell me exacctly what is causing the problem it would be helpful.
Thanks